# Why do I get different results for matmul and solve?

Tags: python, numpy

Why do I get different results for matmul() and solve()?

Ax = b <=> x = A^(-1)b

```
A = np.array(((1, 2, 3), (4, 5, 6), (7, 8, 9)))
b = np.array(((2,), (3,), (4,)))
np.matmul(np.linalg.inv(A), b), np.linalg.solve(A, b)
```

Results:

```
(array([[0.],
        [0.],
        [0.]]),
 array([[-3.33333333],
        [ 5.66666667],
        [-2.        ]]))
```

Comment: I get `numpy.linalg.LinAlgError: Singular matrix` with your code. You can't get an inverse of `A` as it's singular.

Comment: What version of numpy are you using?

Comment: `np.linalg.det(A)` returns 0 btw

Comment: I' m using version 1.19.5